# "verlieren" mit Dativ-Valenz

Tags: dialect, verb-usage

In einem Skatklub in Thüringen habe ich mehrmals den Satz

> Jetzt verlierstes dir.

also in Schriftdeutsch

> Jetzt verlierst du es dir [das Spiel].

gehört. Der Satz drückt aus, dass der Spieler ein bei perfektem Spiel sicher gewonnenes Spiel doch noch durch einen eigenen fehlerhaften Zug für die Gegner gewinnbar macht.

Ich finde die Konstruktion mit der Dativ-Valenz für *verlieren* bemerkenswert, weil ich sie außerhalb dieses Kontexts noch nie gehört habe. *sich etwas verlieren* ist augenscheinlich eine Analogie-Bildung zu *sich etwas gönnen*, *sich etwas leisten*, *sich etwas nehmen* usw. usf., am deutlichsten vielleicht *sich etwas verderben*.

Der semantische Unterschied zum bloßen *etwas verlieren* ist hier klar, dass der aktive Anteil des Adressaten ausgedrückt werden soll, der das Spiel erst durch eigenes Tun verliert. Diese Bedeutung ginge im bloßen

> Jetzt verlierstes.

unter.

Ich habe folgende Fragen dazu:

1. Gibt es noch bessere Beschreibungen dieses Phänomens als meine oben vorgestellte ad-hoc-Analyse?
2. Ist das ein dialektales Phänomen?
3. Gibt es andere Beispiele für Verwendung von *verlieren* mit Dativ-Valenz?

Comment: Finde es eigentlich nicht so weit weg von "Jetzt versaust du es dir / Jetzt versausts dir" oder ähnlichen gängigen Wendungen.

Answer (score 3):

Auf die Bemerkung *"Das sieht aber lecker aus."* habe ich sowohl im Ruhrgebiet als auch im Schwobaländle die Reaktion gehört: *"Na, dann iss' es dir!"* Geklungen hat dies allerdings anders als die vorstehende verschriftete Fassung.

Nur im Ruhrgebiet: *"Ich trink' mir jetzt noch 'n Bier."*

Was du, Jonathan, eine Analogiebildung nennst, nenne ich eine Kontamination. Da sie in (mindestens) drei unterschiedlichen Regionen vorkommen kann, lässt sie sich selbstverständlich unter Regio- oder Dialekt einordnen, aber genauso gut als Phänomen eines Soziolekts.

Dies zu 1. und 2. Zu 3.: Im Französischen durchaus. *Je me suis perdu.*

Comment: Wobei ich den Verdacht hege, dass Deine Beispiele aus starker Verkürzung entsanden sind: *nimm es Dir und iss es* --> *iss es Dir*

Comment: Was bedeutet der Begriff _Kontamination_ in diesem Zusammenhang? Wo kann ich mehr dazu lesen? Wikipedia kennt den Begriff nur im Zusammenhang mit Versprechern. Ich denke nicht, dass es ein Versprecher war. Aber du meinst sicher was anderes, oder?

Answer (score 1):

Zu 1) Ich halte Deine Analyse für zutreffend.
*Jetzt ruinierst Du es Dir* wäre eine weitere Variante, die dem Original sehr ähnlich ist.

Zu 2) Ich nehme es an - zumindest ist mir *verlieren* in dieser Konstruktion noch nie untergekommen.

Zu 3) Der Berliner benutzt ja oft den Dativ, wo eigentlich der Akkusativ hingehört. Also wenn wir beide in einer dichtgedrängten Menschenmenge stecken - da könnt' ick Dir leicht verliern ;-)